# Find hidden elements and store them in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some mark-up like so:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="slide" style="display:block;"></div>
    <div class="slide" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="slide" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="slide" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

Which is basically some divs with one shown and the others hidden.

I'm trying to find the ones that are currently not shown and then randomly select one of them...

```
var length = $('div.slideshow').find('div.slide:hidden').length;

var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length) + 1;
var newSlide = $("div.slideshow > div.slide:nth-child(" + ran + ")");
```

However because their is more than one hidden div it will not work... I'm guessing I need to setup an array? Can anyone help me out here as I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/aNcx7/1/)

```
var $hiddenSlides = $('div.slideshow').find('div.slide:hidden');
var length = $hiddenSlides.length;

var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length );
var newSlide = $hiddenSlides.get(ran);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var $hiddenSlides = $('div.slideshow').find('div.slide:hidden');
var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*$hiddenSlides.length);
var newSlide = $hiddenSlides.get(ran);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("div.slideshow > div.slide:nth-child(" + ran + ")"` selects from all children, including the one that is already visible.
Do you want that?

If so, you have to iterate your selection with

```
$("div.slideshow > div.slide:nth-child(" + ran + ")").each(function() {
    $(this).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
var length = $('div.slideshow').find('div.slide:hidden').length;
var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length);
var newSlide = $(".slideshow .slide:hidden:eq(" + ran + ")");
```

You'll see in this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cpjyT/)** that the output is always one of the hidden divs.

Answer (score 0):

#### explanation:

it won't work because the order of elements is not guaranteed, why not iterate over the elements using the same selector you applied to find the hidden elements?

#### example:

save the visible element:

```
var shownSlide = $("div.slideshow > div.slide:visible");
```

apply the random traversal:

```
var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length) + 1;
$("div.slideshow > div.slide:hidden:eq(" + ran + ")").show();
```

than re-hide the visible element:

```
$(shownSlide).hide();
```